# Check query results before running

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to run my UPDATE statement on my table and see what the results will be without actually changing the table.

For example:

> UPDATE MyTable SET field1=TRIM(field1);

I would like to see the result of that without actually changing the tables content. Is this possible?
Specifically I am asking about MySQL.

Also, I know I could just run a SELECT statement as follows:

> SELECT TRIM(field1) FROM MyTable;

But I would like to know if I can do it the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use a transaction, you can push the content of that table into a temporary table ([`insert select`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)), and do your update on that first.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using InnoDB tables - use a transaction.  If you don't like the results, ROLLBACK - If they are OK, the COMMIT

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE MyTable SET field1=TRIM(field1);

COMMIT; (or ROLLBACK;)
```